# Passing arguments to function in Python

Tags: python, functional-programming

In a simplified example, say I have

```
class Car:
  def __init__(self, operation):
    self.operation = operation

def change_wheels(car, wheel_type):
  ...
def repair_brakes(car, brake_pads, brake_fluid):
  ...

car_list = [Car(change_wheels), Car(repair_brakes)]

def service_car(car, wheel_type, brake_pads, brake_fluid):
  car.operation(???)
```

How do I pass the required arguments to the `operation` function?

Comment: What is `car.operation`? Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example? All callables can be called in the same fashion in Python. If you're running into something unusually when attempting to call `car.operation`, that's relevant information.

Comment: use a list as a parameter, and select the needed values.

Comment: To clarify: you're essentially asking how to deduce the number of arguments that a callable requires and/or how to pass a variable number of arguments to a callable? It may help if you can elaborate on your motive for this design.

Comment: @Brian apologies for lack of clarity - I realized I missed out the step of passing the the `Car` objects from `car_list` into the `service_car` function. `operation` is a function (such as `change_wheels`) and the arguments need to come from the context.

Answer (score 1):

You could give `Car` parameters, like wheel type, brake type, etc. And pass the car object to the functions, then retrieve the car's parameters. These attributes is corresponding to each car, because they have different brake types etc... And passing these objects to the functions makes easier to get the needed parameters later.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, wheel, brakes, operation):
        self.wheel     = wheel
        self.brakes    = brakes
        self.operation = operation

def change_wheels(car):
    print('Wheel', car.wheels)

def repair_brakes(car):
    print('Brakes', car.brakes)

car_list = [Car('Wheel type', 'Brake type', change_wheels), Car('Wheel type', 'Brake type', repair_brakes)]

for car in car_list:
    car.operation(car)
```

Not all parameters were implemented, this is just an example!

Comment: Looks good. Hopefully, you'll get feedback from the person who posted the question.

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh Thanks! Your answer was also good, but I prefer avoid hardcoding. After a few plus functions it gets messy!

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that `car_list` is static and the arguments are not known until I read in a text file, whereupon I classify the file as a type of car. I then want to call the required servicing operations on the car, which depends on the type of car. I've also realized from the downvotes that my question probably sucks in terms of detail.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge Yes, if that was a thing I would suggest args/kwargs. By the way I suggest adding those parameters to the car objects as I did, after you readed the file. This way your code stays well readable.  Or redesign the control structure to create the objects while reading the file. Or did you accept another answer, and this is not what you wanted?

Comment: @LuigiPlinge can you please edit your question with a sample of the content of your text file and the reading process, so I could maybe add a valid solution to my answer?

Comment: Unfortunately I think I've missed a bunch of key details in the question by trying to simplify; `car_list` is a list of valid car types, and each Car object holds a whole bunch of data on how to handle that type. I'll have a rethink and might post a better question. Have an upvote for your efforts!

Comment: @LuigiPlinge Thanks! Edit the question whenever you think, and I'll provide an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want, but how about:

```
class Car:
  def __init__(self, operation):
    self.op = operation
  
  def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try: self.op(self, *args, **kwargs)
    except TypeError: print('Unsupported operation.')

def change_wheels(car, wheel_type):
  print('change_wheels()', wheel_type)

def repair_brakes(car, brake_pads, brake_fluid):
  print('repair_brakes()', brake_pads, brake_fluid)

car_list = [Car(change_wheels), Car(repair_brakes)]

def service_car(car, wheel_type, brake_pads, brake_fluid):
  #car.operation(???)
  car(wheel_type)
  car(brake_pads, brake_fluid)

for car in car_list: service_car(car, 'wt', 'bp', 'bf')
```

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, this solution depends on the number of arguments being passed? Unfortunately I can't guarantee that this is going to be different for each operation.

Comment: You pass whatever operation you want explicitly, at construction (see `__init__()`). It doesn't care how many args you pass to the operation later: they will get bunched up in *args and **kwargs. (Edited code, maybe clearer now.)

Comment: But let's say that there's another operation which takes 1 arg, like `def change_oil(car, oil)`. I would get `change_oil` called with the `wheel_type` argument.

Comment: Correct: in that case, it won't be able to differentiate.